# how to control number of controls shown react tanstack tables pagination

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, tanstack

```
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
  import './index.css';
  import {
    Column,
    Table,
    useReactTable,
    ColumnFiltersState,
    getCoreRowModel,
    getFilteredRowModel,
    getFacetedRowModel,
    getFacetedUniqueValues,
    getFacetedMinMaxValues,
    getPaginationRowModel,
    sortingFns,
    getSortedRowModel,
    FilterFn,
    SortingFn,
    ColumnDef,
    flexRender,
    FilterFns,
  } from '@tanstack/react-table';
  import {
    RankingInfo,
    rankItem,
    compareItems,
  } from '@tanstack/match-sorter-utils';
  import { makeData, Person } from './makeData';

  // ... (rest of your code)

  function App() {
    // ... (existing code)

    return (
      <div className="p-2">
        {/* Global Filter Input */}
        <div>
          <DebouncedInput
            value={globalFilter ?? ''}
            onChange={value => setGlobalFilter(String(value))}
            className="p-2 font-lg shadow border border-block"
            placeholder="Search all columns..."
          />
        </div>
        <div className="h-2" />
        
        {/* Pagination Controls */}
        <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <button
            className="border rounded p-1"
            onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(0)}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            {'<<'}
          </button>
          <button
            className="border rounded p-1"
            onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            {'<'}
          </button>
          <button
            className="border rounded p-1"
            onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            {'>'}
          </button>
          <button
            className="border rounded p-1"
            onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(table.getPageCount() - 1)}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            {'>>'}
          </button>
          <span className="flex items-center gap-1">
            <div>Page</div>
            <strong>
              {table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1} of{' '}
              {table.getPageCount()}
            </strong>
          </span>
          <span className="flex items-center gap-1">
            | Go to page:
            <input
              type="number"
              defaultValue={table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1}
              onChange={e => {
                const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0;
                table.setPageIndex(page);
              }}
              className="border p-1 rounded w-16"
            />
          </span>
          <select
            value={table.getState().pagination.pageSize}
            onChange={e => {
              table.setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
            }}
          >
            {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
              <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                Show {pageSize}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>{table.getPrePaginationRowModel().rows.length} Rows</div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => rerender()}>Force Rerender</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => refreshData()}>Refresh Data</button>
        </div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(table.getState(), null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // ... (rest of your code)

  const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
  if (!rootElement) throw new Error('Failed to find the root element');

  ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

I have a table with 100 pages, and I want to add navigation buttons to allow users to easily move between pages. For example, if a user is currently on page number 5, I want to display buttons for pages 6, 7, and 8, as well as previous and next page buttons. How can I implement this pagination functionality in my React application using the TanStack React Table library?

I have a table with 100 pages, and I want to add navigation buttons to allow users to easily move between pages. For example, if a user is currently on page number 5, I want to display buttons for pages 6, 7, and 8, as well as previous and next page buttons. How can I implement this pagination functionality in my React application using the TanStack React Table library?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this pagination code snippet will be useful in your project. Personally, I've tested it and it worked correctly for me.

```html
<Button
  variant="outlined"
  size="sm"
  onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
  disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
>
  Previous
</Button>

<div className="flex items-center gap-2">
  {Array.from({ length: table.getPageCount() }).map((_, index) => (
    <IconButton
      key={index}
      variant="outlined"
      size="sm"
      onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(index)}
      disabled={table.getState().pagination.pageIndex === index}
    >
      {index + 1}
    </IconButton>
  ))}
</div>
<Button
  variant="outlined"
  size="sm"
  onClick={() => table.nextPage(0)}
  disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
>
  Next
</Button>
```